# Having issues creating a query with an inner join and an outer join

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I have the following model (simplified):

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class Thing(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'thing'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class Relationship(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'relationship'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('thing.id'))
    parent = relationship('Thing', backref='parentrelationships', primaryjoin = "Relationship.parent_id == Thing.id")
    child_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('thing.id'))
    child = relationship('Thing', backref='childrelationships', primaryjoin = "Relationship.child_id == Thing.id")

class Vote(Base)
    __tablename__ = 'vote'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    rel_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('relationship.id'))
    rel = relationship('Relationship', backref='votes')
    voter_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
    voter = relationship('User', backref='votes')
```

I wanted to query all Relationships with a certain parent, and I also want to query votes made by a certain user on those Relationships. What I've tried:

```
def get_relationships(thisthing, thisuser):
    return DBSession.query(Relationship, Vote).\
        filter(Relationship.parent_id == thisthing.id).\
        outerjoin(Vote, Relationship.id == Vote.rel_id).\
        filter(Vote.voter_id == thisuser.id).\
        filter(Vote.rel_id == Relationship.id).\
        all()
```

as well as:

```
def get_relationships(thisthing, thisuser):
    session = DBSession()
    rels = session.query(Relationship).\
        filter(Relationship.parent_id == thisthing.id).\ 
        subquery()
    return session.query(rels, Vote).\
        outerjoin(Vote, rels.c.id == Vote.rel_id).\
        filter(Vote.voter_id == thisuser.id).\
        all()
```

I get nulls when I do either of these queries. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just turn on SQL logging (`echo=True`) and you will see that the resulting SQL query for the first option is something like:

```
SELECT relationship.id AS relationship_id, relationship.parent_id AS relationship_parent_id, relationship.child_id AS relationship_child_id, vote.id AS vote_id, vote.rel_id AS vote_rel_id, vote.voter_id AS vote_voter_id 
FROM relationship LEFT OUTER JOIN vote ON relationship.id = vote.rel_id 
WHERE relationship.parent_id = ? AND vote.voter_id = ? AND vote.rel_id = relationship.id
```

If you examine it, you will notice that the clause `vote.rel_id = relationship.id` is part of both the `JOIN` clause and the `WHERE` clause, which makes the query to filter out those `Relationship` rows which do not have any votes by requested user.

**Solution:**

1. Remove redundant `filter(Vote.rel_id == Relationship.id).` part from the query.
2. **Edit-1**: Also move (remove) the filter for the user `filter(Vote.voter_id == thisuser.id)` out of `WHERE` and into the `LEFT JOIN` clause:  `outerjoin(Vote, and_(Relationship.id == Vote.rel_id, Vote.voter_id == thisuser.id))`.

Comment: thanks man, it doesn't error now. however, when i try to extract the information, rows where Vote is null are not returned. from what I understand about left outer joins, the row should be returned regardless if the right join is null. what am i doing wrong? I am extracting the objects using:

for a, b in get_relationships(thisthing, thisuser):
   # Do this

Comment: With the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` the left side of the join (`Relationship`) will be returned if if the no matching rows for the right side (`Vote`) are found, but the `NULL/None` will be returned. What would you like to see instead?

Comment: I would like it to act like an left outer join, but right now it's acting like an inner join even though I am using outerjoin(). ( Relationship ) is not being returned when ( Vote ) is not found, although I should except ( NULL ).

Comment: Can you post the exact `SA query` and the generated `SQL` query?

Comment: this is exactly what i have:

`reltypes = ['legalstatus', 'focus', 'method', 'operation', 'tagged']`
`return DBSession.query(Relationship, Votebin_Rel).outerjoin(Votebin_Rel).filter(Relationship.reltype.in_(reltypes)).filter(Relationship.childblocked == False).filter(Relationship.parent == thing).filter(Votebin_Rel.voter == currentuser).all()`

Comment: the SQL query is too long and i don't know how to message. Here's the last part without the aliases:
`FROM relationship LEFT OUTER JOIN votebin ON relationship.id = votebin.rel_id 
WHERE relationship.reltype IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) AND relationship.childblocked = ? AND relationship.parent_id = ? AND votebin.voter_id = ? AND votebin.votetype IN (?)`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4618/discussion-between-van-and-jonathan-ong)